# Do the lim sup and lim inf always exist?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits, convergence-divergence, limsup-and-liminf

Let's focus on the $\lim \inf$. While trying to prove that the $\lim \inf$ always exists, [this page]https://mathcs.org/analysis/reals/numseq/proofs/lub_ex.html established that the sequence $A_j = \inf\{a_j, a_{j+1}, \dots\}$ is monotone increasing then the $\lim \inf$ exists even though it may be possibly infinite.

My question is that if we define the limit of a sequence as a real number as [the same page]https://mathcs.org/analysis/reals/numseq/sequence.html has done then how do we reconcile this definition to allow for "a limit that is infinite"?

Comment: It's just a matter of usage (or convention.)  There's no need to reconcile anything.

Comment: I feel as though it is contradictory. If a sequence "converges to infinity" then $\nexists$ a real number c such that $\forall \epsilon > 0$ there is an integer $N > 0$ such that if $j > N$ then $ | a_{j} - c| < \epsilon $.

Comment: It always exist in $\overline{\mathbb R}=\mathbb R\cup\{-\infty ,+\infty \}$.

Comment: That is not how "converges to $\infty$" is defined.  $a_n\to\infty$ means that $\forall M>0\ \exists N>0$ such that $n>N\implies a_n>M$.  You can't just take the definition of a sequence converging to a real (or complex) number and apply it in some other context.

Comment: But even in the extended reals how do you use the definition of convergence to prove that $\infty$ is actually a limit? What $N$ can you choose for an $\epsilon$ of 10 for example?

Comment: @VyktaWakandigara: The neighborhoods of $\infty$ look a bit different from the $\epsilon$-nbhds that you use in $\Bbb R$ proper, but they behave very similarly; see my answer (though I grant that it’s the barest sketch).

Comment: I prefer to use convergence only for finite limit. For infinite limit one can use the phrase _diverges to $\infty$_. Apart from this a sequence can _oscillate finitely or infinitely_. Under this convention "diverge" is _not same_ as "not converge". Treating $\pm\infty $ in a manner similar to real numbers just to save on typing leads to confusion.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The presentation is just a little sloppy, in that the authors have not previously explained that a sequence that increases (decreases, resp.) without bound is said to converge to $+\infty$ ($-\infty$, resp.), but the idea should be clear anyway. It is not really contradictory: it is just an extension of the earlier definition.

And it is entirely compatible with that definition once you know a bit of topology. One forms the [extended real numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_real_number_line) by adjoining points $-\infty$ and $+\infty$ and giving them nbhds analogous to $\epsilon$-nbhds $(a-\epsilon,a+\epsilon)$ around real numbers. Specifically, just as we say that a sequence $\langle x_n:n\in\Bbb N\rangle$ converges to $a$ if and only if for each $\epsilon>0$ there is an $n_0\in\Bbb N$ such that $x_n\in(a-\epsilon,a+\epsilon)$ for all $n\ge n_0$. we say that it converges to $+\infty$ if and only if for each $b\in\Bbb R$ there is an $n_0\in\Bbb N$ such that $x_n>b$ for all $n\ge n_0$. The open rays

$$(b,\to)=\{+\infty\}\cup\{x\in\Bbb R:x>b\}$$

function as the equivalent at $+\infty$ of open intervals $(a-\epsilon,a+\epsilon)$ at $a$. And just as at $a$ it generally suffices to work just with the countable family of intervals $\left(a-\frac1n,a+\frac1n\right)$, so at $+\infty$ we can generally work just with the countable family of rays $(m,\to)$ for $m\in\Bbb Z$.

The notion of convergence of a sequence to $-\infty$ is defined similarly: $\langle x_n:n\in\Bbb N\rangle$ converges to $-\infty$ if and only if for each $b\in\Bbb R$ there is an $n_0\in\Bbb N$ such that $x_n<b$ for all $n\ge n_0$.

From a topological point of view convergence to $\infty$ or $-\infty$ behaves no differently from convergence to some $a\in\Bbb R$; both are instances of a more general notion of sequential convergence. And it is convenient to make the extension even at this early point, because sequences that diverge in $\Bbb R$ because they converge to $\infty$ or $-\infty$ in the extended reals, rather than for other reasons (like $\langle (-1)^n:n\in\Bbb N\rangle$, for instance) are quite well-behaved and can often be treated right along with those that converge to real numbers.

Comment: This is a great answer! That link between convergence to the $\infty (-\infty)$ and convergence to a real number was really cool.