# $\lim\inf x_n$ can possibly be $-\infty$ or $\infty$? Either or Both?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits, convergence-divergence, limsup-and-liminf

> Show that $\lim\inf x_n$ always exists for any sequence $x_n$ of real numbers and can possibly be $-\infty$.

Proof for the existence part is easy if I assume the sequence is bounded finitely. It follows from the Monotone Convergence Theorem. [For infinite case also](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3666826/562589), if the definition of convergence to a limit holds for the sequence $\{\inf_{k\ge n}x_n\}_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$, we can extend ourselves and say that it is bounded above by $\infty$ and
$$\sup_n(\inf_{k\ge n}x_n)\text{ is the upper bound of the sequence }\{\inf_{k\ge n}x_n\}\text{ i.e., }\infty.$$

Is this wrong? I got the above question in class and it specifically mentions that $\lim\inf x_n$ might be $-\infty$. Shouldn't that be $\infty$ as I proved above, or even logically from the defintion of $\lim\inf x_n=\sup\inf_{k\ge n}x_k$ (being the supremum of some sequence and possibly being $-\infty$ doesn't make sense).

Comment: imagine $x_n=-n$. What is $\xi_n=\inf\limits_{k\geq n}x_k$?(note your notation is off) What is its supremum over all $n$? btw if the liminf equals $+\infty$, then the limit also exists in the extended sense and equals $\infty$.

Comment: @peek-a-boo oh right it is inf over $x+k$'s. Also, got it! When the sequence itself goes to $-\infty$ like in your ex., the liminf is the same too. How can I possibly explain this in words thought- the proof i.e.

Comment: Well, that's a general theorem to be proved: for any sequence, the $\liminf$ and $\limsup$ always exist in $[-\infty,\infty]$, and that $\liminf\leq \limsup$. The limit exists in $[-\infty,\infty]$ if and only if $\liminf=\limsup$, in which case all 3 are equal $\liminf=\lim=\limsup$. Everything above needs to be interpreted in the extended $[-\infty,\infty]$ sense so that the theorem statement is clean and general (otherwise there are undue restrictions). For my particular example above, it is easy to see $\xi_n=-\infty$ for all $n$, and hence $\liminf x_n=\sup\xi_n=\sup\{-\infty\}=-\infty$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given a sequence of real numbers, we can consider the set of accumulation points in the extended real number line. The set is non-empty and it has a minimum. The minimum is called the limes inferior. A convergent sequence has precisely one accumulation point, namely its limit.

That being said, $\infty$ is the limes inferior if and only if the sequence converges to $\infty$ and the limes inferior equals $-\infty$ if and only if the sequence is not bounded from below.